# How to use google analytics tag in chrome extension to know user behavior in my extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

```
await fetch(
    `${"https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect"
        }?measurement_id=${MEASUREMENT_ID}`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        client_id: await getClientId(),
        events: [
          {
            name,
            params,
          },
        ],
      }),
    }
  ).then(async(res)=>{
    console.log(await res.json());
  })
```

Which work with API secret but I want to use with only measurement id

I want to use Google Analytics into my chrome extension and I don't know how. I try the above approach, but it doesn't work without API secret